# How Can I Update Build Definition's Step

Tags: c#, rest, tfs

I am using TFS 2018 and I want update my steps of definition build with restful api. But When I am lookin Restfull documentation for TFS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update%20definition?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) , I cant see steps in parameters. Just I saw the type of process .

Is it possible update step of process with restful-api?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to send an appropriate request body. The documentation explains what a request body should contain. The easiest way to approach it is to `GET` the definition, update it, then use the API to `PUT` it back.

Comment: If you look the documentation you will se the  "                                      BuildProcess
Represents a build process.
Name  = type 
Type  =integer 
Description   = The type of the process.
"
So According to this documentation , we can update just type of process